# Is it forbidden to embarrass a non-Jew?

Tags: gentiles, social-media, embarrassment, onaath-devarim

The prohibition to embarrass another and its sources are discussed [here](https://www.ou.org/torah/mitzvot/taryag/mitzvah240/) and at more length [here](http://etzion.org.il/vbm/english/archive/chavero2/10chavero.htm), with the stipulation that the mitzvah--and related issues of onaat devarim--apply to men and women in all times and places. However, would these technically apply to the issue of embarrassing non-Jews, too? (I have little question about what is right, or what would be a better demonstration of middos, but I am wondering about Torah law.)

Motivation: Have had the temptation to say some snide things online about a certain politician, and I don't mean Bernie Sanders.

Comment: It is clear to me that it is a Torah prohibition. If tzar baalei chayim applies to humans (as a Torah law), then it is forbidden. Also, the second article you referenced quotes Rav Shlomo Aviner who says that since embarrassing others may shorten their lifespan, it is forbidden to do so under the category of murder. Also, if it is not subjectively 'right' because the custom of most nations around the world today is that humans do not embarrass each other, then besides for being a chillul Hashem, it would fall under the Torah category of doing what is 'straight and good' (Deuteronomy 6:18).

Answer (score 3):

ת"ר: מפרנסים עניי נכרים עם עניי ישראל, ומבקרין חולי נכרים עם חולי ישראל, וקוברין מתי נכרים עם מתי ישראל, מפני דרכי שלום.

תלמוד בבלי, גיטין סא.

Would this lesson about treating Jews and non-Jews equally apply here?
We sustain the non-Jewish poor with the Jewish poor, visit the non-Jewish sick with the Jewish sick, and bury the non-Jewish dead with the Jewish dead, for the sake of peace.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable Kol VaHomer

Comment: @DoubleAA Counter to the Kol VaHomer - those are all ***positive*** actions about helping groups of poor and visiting groups of sick indiscriminately. We're discussing the reverse case - targeted negative acts. The logic of the (well formed) KvH may not apply.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky That just supports it. It's more of a Chiddush that Darkei Shalom obligates us to go out and do something, than for it to tell us not to be mean.

Comment: @user11615 If you could translate the quote, that would be great. The other thing is: there are a lot of areas of Jewish law that apply very differently to Jews than to non-Jews--loshon hara and usury, for example. These hold stricter standards about how to treat Jews than non-Jews. I don't like them at all, but such is the law.